# Figma shadow effect to flutter?

Tags: css, flutter, button, shadow, figma

Does anyone know how to apply this shadow effect to buttons? I'm working with a Figma design as a reference for my first Flutter project, and there's an inner shadow effect there, but for Flutter, I've only found ways to create shadows that are outside the button.

[The Button should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK83U.png)

The only thing I can think of is downloading the button as an SVG file and make the SVG behave like a button, but this would mean I would lose the default behavior for FloatingActionButton-Widgets like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYbuE.png

Comment: Seems like the best solution now is using some third-party library (there are a few). You can read more about this feature discussion here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18636